# extract feature dots position on Arabic character

Tags: matlab, ocr, svm

How to extract feature dots position on Arabic character script if the position of the point is divided into the upper zone, middle zone and the lower zone? For information these features will be classified using SVM!

Answer (score 0):

Try HOG features, it is very success with SVM. 
for example:

```
% Read images from it's path
images_1 = imread(full_name);

[featureVector, hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(images_1);

figure
    % Show all images
    imshow(images_1); hold on;                  
    plot(hogVisualization);
```

You will get HOG features, then you can save it in vector and use it with SVM.
If you have many pictures, you can put above code in loop and save it in matrix.

Comment: thank abu-qusay, but i use freeman chain code (FCC) to extract main body of character. My problem is how to extract dots position and number of dots